# Habilitar navigationbar ou criar um painel em cima das tabpage xamarin.form

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Tenho essa página(TabbedPage) que cria duas tabs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Operacional.Views"
            x:Class="Operacional.Views.MainPage">

    <TabbedPage.Children> 
        <NavigationPage Title="Indicadores">
            <NavigationPage.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_about.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </NavigationPage.Icon>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:Indicadores />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage Title="Paineis">
            <NavigationPage.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_feed.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </NavigationPage.Icon>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:PaineisPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

O que passa é que eu não estou conseguindo habilitar a `NavigationBar` ou pelo menos criar um painel acima das `tabpages`. O ideal seria habilitar a `NavigationBar`, esse seria o ideal pra mim. Como funciona. Ao abrir o `App`, ele cai numa tela de login. Ao fazer o login, então entra a `MainPage` e nela as `TabPages`. Se eu tento exeibir a `NavigationBar` não dá nenhum erro, mas não exibe. Ou ela está **hide** ou as `TabPages` estão "matando" ela. Abaixo os meus códigos.
MainPage

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
    {
        public MainPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);            
        }
    }
```

a tela de login

```
public  void Login_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoginService svc = new LoginService();
            LoginRS res = svc.Login(txtUsuario.Text, txtSenha.Text);
            if (res != null && res.Success  )
            {
                App.LooggedUser = res;
                Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
            }
            else if(res != null && ! res.Success)
            {
                lblErroLogin.Text = res.Exception;
            }
            else
            {
                lblErroLogin.Text = "Não foi possível realizar o Login, por favor verifique sua conexão com a Internet";
            }
        }
```

e o meu App.xaml.cs

```
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (!IsUserLoggedIn)
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
            }
            else
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, este é um assunto delicado. Apesar de ser possível, não é recomendado.

A implementação seria você alterar o código do botão de login, onde você altera a MainPage do app, para colocar a `TabbedPage` dentro de uma `NavigationPage` da mesma forma como você fez no `else` do `OnStart`, assim:

```
public  void Login_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoginService svc = new LoginService();
    LoginRS res = svc.Login(txtUsuario.Text, txtSenha.Text);
    if (res != null && res.Success  )
    {
        App.LooggedUser = res;
        Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
    else if(res != null && ! res.Success)
        lblErroLogin.Text = res.Exception;
    else
        lblErroLogin.Text = "Não foi possível realizar o Login, por favor verifique sua conexão com a Internet";
    }
}
```

E quando fosse navegar a partir dalí, usar a Navigation da página principal, em vez da Navigation da `TabbedPage`:

```
App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new NovaPage());
```

**Sobre o fato de não ser recomendado:**

Uma vez que o Xamarin.Forms é multi plataforma, é importante que você escreva seus Apps de modo que a usabilidade seja "fluente" em cada uma delas no momento da execução.

Nesse caso específico, como você pode consultar [neste artigo do site de desenvolvedores Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page/#Populating_a_TabbedPage_with_a_Page_Collection), teríamos um problema na interface do iOS.

Em uma tradução livre do alerta do site:

> Apesar de ser sensato admitir NavigationPages dentro da TabbedPage, não recomendamos que você coloque uma TabbedPage dentro de uma NavigationPage, pois no iOS a UITabBarController sempre age como uma embalagem para a UINavigationController.

Nesta citação o site recomenda dar uma conferida na guideline referente a esste assunto: [Combined View Controller Interfaces](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html).

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Diego,valeu pela explicação. Vou testar e posto o result. A vantagem aqui, é que apesar de ser Forms, esse projeto vai rodar apenas no **Android**, ufa!!

Comment: Diego, só uma pergunta, como eu faço para deixar o backgroundcolor da NavigationBar de outra cor? Estou tentando na MainPage e está dando erro. Como faço?

Comment: @pnet, se importa em postar isso como outra pergunta? Isso é um ponto de dúvida comun na comunidade e eu acho que ficaria mais fácil para outros encontrarem a resposta se a pergunta for dedicada exclusivamente a isso. (y) Valeu!

Comment: Sim, claro, de fato é outra pergunta. Foi mal. Vou abrir outra thread.